# JavaScript Console.log() method is outputting the function before the text given inside it

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and was facing this error when I have executed the following code.
I have created a class and was trying to use it to create objects from it.

1. Computer.js

```
  constructor(
    // defining the parameters
    name,
    modelName,
    sizeInInches,
    color,
    type,
    generation,
    clockSpeed,
    ramSize,
    diskSize,
    diskType
  ) {
    // defining the properties
    this.name = name;
    this.modelName = modelName;
    this.sizeInInches = sizeInInches;
    this.color = color;
    this.type = type;
    this.processorSpecs = {
      generation: generation,
      clockSpeed: clockSpeed,
      type: type,
    };
    this.ramSize = ramSize;
    this.diskType = diskType;
    this.diskSize = diskSize;
  }
  // adding the methods here
  outputConsole() {
    console.log(this.name, this.ramSize, this.color, this.diskSize);
  }
}

export default Computer;
```

2. Script.js

```
import Computer from "./Computer.js";

const myComp = new Computer(
  "Pranav's HP Laptop",
  "HP-envym6-1225dx",
  15,
  "Grey",
  "Intel i5",
  "3rd-Generation",
  "2.2GHz",
  "8.0 GB",
  "HDD",
  "750.0 GB"
);

console.log("Output object created\n", myComp);
console.log("Output the method\n", myComp.outputConsole());
console.log("Program Finished");
```

3. index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Practice: Making classes and objects</title>
    <script type="module" src="Computer.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

[This is the output I have obtained][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8afX0.png

Why is the `myComp.outputConsole()` being displayed before the `"Output the method\n"` in the code `console.log("Output the method\n", myComp.outputConsole());`?
Please give me assistance about where i am going wrong. Thanks in advance!! :).

Comment: it runs first, before the containing console.log - because the containing console.log needs to know what that function returns before it can console.log it

Comment: Because you are using the function call as an argument, so it has to be evaluated(run in this case) before the value returned(`undefined` since you dont return anything) from it can be passed as an argument to the `log` function

Comment: Because The containing console.log will have to execute first function call then it will console itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because your method is calling console.log inside it.

When you call it on this line

```
console.log("Method output", myComp.outputConsole());
```

The external console.log must execute myComp.outputConsole() before it executes itself. The text inside the outputConsole method is shown before the text "Method output" because myComp.outputConsole() does not return anything and executes an internal console.log. Once the method is resolved, console.log("Method output") is executed.

To obtain the expected result you could simply separate the console logs.

```
console.log("Method output")
myComp.outputConsole(); // this will also be printed because you implemented the internal console.log
```

Or you can change your method to return a string

```
  outputConsole() {
    return this.name +""+ this.ramSize +""+ this.color +""+ this.diskSize;
  }
```